# runtime instantiated class cannot access the interface it implements

Tags: java

I have two classes interfaceTestA and interfaceTestB. They have
an arraylist called 'myList' and a method, 'makeString()' in commom.
MyList is defined in an interface named hasList and makeString is
implemented in an abstract class getTheData. So both of them extend
getTheData and implement hasList. Compiling and running, for example,
interfaceTestA works just fine. In particular it has access to myList.

But now, in a class called ifTest, I want to instantiate one of the
two known only at run time. My problem is that when instantiated
this way, it does not know about myList.  See the listings.

```
import java.util.*;

interface hasList { ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(); }
//===
abstract class getTheData {
  public String makeString() { return "Hi Mom"; }
}
//===
public class
interfaceTestA extends getTheData implements hasList
{
  public interfaceTest() {
    setString();
    System.out.println("size= "+myList.size());
  }

  void setString() { myList.add(makeString()); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    interfaceTestA it = new interfaceTestA();
  }
}

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class
ifTest
{
  public static void
  main(String[] args)
  {
    Class prog = Class.forName("interfaceTestA");
    getTheData gtd = (interfaceTestA) prog.newInstance();
    System.out.println("myList size= "+gtd.myList.size());

  }
}
```

Comment: `gtd` should be declared as `interfaceTestA`, not `getTheData`.  This is very basic Java wrt its static type system.

Comment: An abstract class (`getTheData`) cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @SHG I think the program compiles up to the last line, although I didn't try it.  The abstract class is being used as a type, not instantiated.  `interfaceTestA` is being instantiated.

Comment: The constructor and class names must match.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 0):

`interfaceTestA` is child of `hasList` but `getTheData` is not. In your code, type of `gtd` is `getTheData` so that it can not see the `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Create a new abstract class that combines both, e.g.        abstract class combined extends getTheData implements hasList. Now
declare gtd to be of type combined, e.g. combined gtd = (interfaceTestA)prog.newInstance().

And it now works.  Thanks for the help.